# How do show an embedded conditional if es6 for double variables

Tags: javascript

I have my condition :

```
{ empty === false ? <p>Empty</p> : <p>Not Empty</p> }
```

But i've added 2 variables... if `var1Empty` and if `var2Empty`... How can I make that work in an embedded conditional in jsx es6? If both variables are found empty, then show "empty".

this is what i have:

```
{ var1Empty && var2Empty === false ? <p>Empty</p> : <p>Not Empty</p> }
```

Comment: what does 'empty' mean?

Comment: Read up on how the logical AND operator works. It's really fundamental, and I don't think you should be writing production code if you don't understand it.

Comment: @madox2 if the array is empty :3

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Never said anything about production code.. :P but thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both variables are either true or false (i.e. not undefined, null, etc.):

```
{ (var1Empty && var2Empty) ? <p>Empty</p> : <p>Not Empty</p> }
```

assuming that var1Empty being `true` means that it's empty (Your example above checks that `empty === false` in order to show "Empty" which seems a bit backwards.